# Firebase.auth() No es una función

Tags: javascript, firebase

Trato de realizar un login usando firebase, pero me sale un error de consola

"Firebase.auth() is not a function"

Por lo cual no me deja realizar el logueo, de resto todo el código compila y funciona la conexión a firebase

```
 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB3RD_EJOPuLQXADQGzjhYBQLresq2bqzw",
    authDomain: "ecommerce-2d647.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://ecommerce-2d647.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "ecommerce-2d647",
    storageBucket: "ecommerce-2d647.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "949533636518",
    appId: "1:949533636518:web:2a1472dede404f8a"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('correo');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('pass');
  const btnLogin = document.getElementById('login'); 

  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
const email = txtEmail.value;
const pass = txtPassword.value;
const auth = firebase.auth();

const promesa = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emails,pass);
promesa.catch(e => location.href = "admin/error.php");


});


 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
if (firebaseUser) {

  location.href = "admin";
}

 });
```

Además en otro archivo tengo la inclusión a firebase

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltaría el `auth`.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```